# Why is Bundler is vendoring ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I have a bunch of Rails3 projects under active development, and Bundler normally behaves just fine. On one project, whenever I run `bundle install`, it vendorizes ruby its self -- binaries and all. Why? How can I stop this?

Project in question:

```
...
/vendor
  /ruby
    /1.9.1
      /bin
      ...
  /plugins
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/848317

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `.bundle/config` at the root of your project. it is probably configured to do this.

Comment: --- 
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "1"

Comment: I removed `BUNDLE_PATH: vendor`, re-installed the gems and viola. Thanks!